# JPA multiselect

Tags: jpa, criteria

I am using EclipseLink as JPA provider.

I want to make a query to get me all the names that correspond to certain `IDs` with online one Criteria query.

```
Root<UserAccount> root = criteria.from(UserAccount.class);
List<Selection<?>> select = new ArrayList<Selection<?>>();
    for (MyElement element : list) {
   Expression<String> firstName = root.get("firstName");
   Expression<String> lastName = root.get("lastName");
   Expression<Integer> id = root.get("id");
   select.add(criteria
                .multiselect(
                        firstName.alias(element.getId() + "_"
                                + element.getEntity() + "f"),
                        lastName.alias(element.getId() + "_"
                                + element.getEntity() + "l"))
                .where(criteriaBuilder.equal(id, element.getAuthorId()))
                .from(UserAccount.class)
                .alias(element.getId() + "_" + element.getEntity()));
}
criteria.multiselect(select);
TypedQuery<Tuple> q = em.createQuery(criteria);
for (Tuple t : q.getResultList()) {
        for (OverviewEntity element : list) {
 System.out.println("////"
                        + t.get(element.getId().toString() + "_"+element.getEntity()+"f",
                                String.class));
```

By `element.getId() + "_" + element.getEntity() + "f"` I intend to create a unique alias.

The problem is that all I get is `null`. Why? How should I get all these in one query(so that it will not become time-consuming)?

Comment: Why do you want to create (unique) aliases? What's element.getEntity()?

Comment: @perissf The idea is that when I get the results,I want to know where do all the results fit. The `ID` isn't enough, there is some more `@Transient`(not in the database) information.

Comment: This design seems much complicated. I would write a plain query returning all UserAccount records with an Id in the given set. The resultList will be attached to PersistenceContext, and you'll be able to get your Transient property without any effort...no need to use aliases

Comment: @perissf You are right, it might be easier to get them and having the list, sort all the problems out by iterating through it. But doesn't that make my query slower(because I get the entire entity, and not only those 3 fields)? Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, I would go for a simpler solution like

```
List<Integer> myList = ....;  // place here your ids
TypedQuery<UserAccount> q = em.createQuery("select u from UserAccount u where u.id in (:myList)", UserAccount.class);
```

or the equivalent query using `CriteriaBuilder` and Metamodel:

```
Root<UserAccount> root = q.from(UserAccount.class);
Expression<Integer> exp = root.get(UserAccount_.id);
Predicate predicate = exp.in(myList);
criteria.where(predicate);
```

The `resultList` returned contains entity instances that are attached to the `PersistenceContext`. This means that you'll be able to get the `Transient` properties without effort.

Concerning the performances, there might be notable differences only in extreme situations like when the size of the returned list is very big, or when you have to repeat this query with a high frequency. But this requires a deep analysis.

Answer (score 8):

Your code seems very confused and over complicated.

The JPQL

```
Select u.firstName, u.lastName, u.id from UserAccount u where u.id in (:ids)
```

Would seem to work,

In criteria this is,

```
Root<UserAccount> root = criteria.from(UserAccount.class);
criteria.multiselect(root.get("firstName"), root.get("lastName"), root.get("id"));
criteria.where(criteriaBuilder.in(root.get("id"), criteriaBuilder.parameter("ids"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the provided code. Still, the problem is this: one `element` can be of type `A` or of type 'B'. I can find out what type it is like this: `element.getEntity()`. When I get the results, I should know whether the returned `id` and it's corresponding `firstName` and `lastName` belong to an `A` or to a `B`. THAT is the problem, not just getting the Strings from the database.